# From Lower Cases to Upper Cases Quote Console App

Tags: c++, char

I have a console app which takes an  input.  The user inputs a text such as "It's better to be a '<'good man'>' rather than a '<succesful man'>" , and transforms it like so : "It's better to be a '<'GOOD MAN'>' rather than a '<SUCCESFUL MAN'>".

I did the following script but beeing C++ newbie it doesn t quite work and I get the following output:"It's better to be a '<good man'>' rather than a '<SUCCESFUL MAN'>"
Note:the program can have multiple "quotes".
This is my attept :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;
char a[]="It's better to be a <good man> rather than a <succesful man>",*p;
int x,y,bec1,bec2;
int main()
{

    for(int i=0;i<strlen(a);i++){
        if(a[i]=='<'){
            x=i;
            bec1=1;
        }
        if(a[i]=='>'){
            y=i;
            bec2=1;
        }
        if(bec1==1 && bec2==1)
            for(int j=x+1;j<y;j++){
                if(a[j]!=' ')
                    a[j]-=32;

                if(j==y){
                    bec1=0;
                    bec2=0;
                }

            }
        }
    cout<<a;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I would suggest you to use `std::to_upper` and family of helper functions instead of manually adding or subtracting and doing ASCII value conversions. Also makes the code a lot more readable. Don't use strlen() in a loop, it causes your code to slow down significantly for bigger string sizes. If you're learning C++, use `std::string`. Set your `bec1` and `bec2` to 0 outside the loop. Null initialise your pointers. Keep your variables in a limited scope rather than global if possible. Get into the habit of using better variable names than one or two character syllables.

Comment: `if(j==y){` condition can never be true - this statement is inside the loop that only runs when `j<y`

Comment: Apart from some odd corner conditions a 2 state state machine: state 1 looking for '<' (just output the char). Once you find '<' go to state 2: looking for '>' and convert everything to uppercase until you find a '>' (and go back to state 1)

Comment: Thanks you Igor . Didn t saw that . It solved the problem ; thanks for pointing that out